# Why isn't my WeakSet empty after deleting the only other reference?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, weak-references

I decided I should familiarize myself with the [`weakref` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html), so I started messing around with the collections, thought I was getting the hang of it until this.

```
>>> import weakref

>>> class Greek():
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

>>> objs = [Greek('alpha'), Greek('gamma'), Greek('zeta')]
>>> weak_s = weakref.WeakSet()

>>> for obj in objs: weak_s.add(obj)
```

Here I have a WeakSet `weak_s` that I would expect to contain 3 `weakref`s to each `Greek()` instance, and it does:

```
>>>  weak_s.data
{<weakref at 0x02ECA690; to 'Greek' at 0x02E5FF90>,
 <weakref at 0x02ECA720; to 'Greek' at 0x02E5FFB0>,
 <weakref at 0x02ECA750; to 'Greek' at 0x02E5FFD0>}
```

Then I would expect that as soon as I get rid of the `objs` name, there won't be any more "strong references" to each `Greek()` instance, and they will be garbage collected. But for some reason this doesn't happen.

```
>>> del objs
>>> weak_s.data
{<weakref at 0x02ECA750; to 'Greek' at 0x02E5FFD0>}
```

Why is there still a weakref inside my WeakSet? I can use `del` again and it persists, seemingly no matter what I do.

Comment: Where did `Foo` come from?

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, edited. (Gave up halfway through changing to Foo).

Comment: Please copy-paste your code and results from an actual interpreter session. Don't try to retype output into the question box or edit it manually to "fix" spotted errors; you'll just obscure the actual behavior of your code.

Comment: @user2357112 Ill keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have the `obj` variable from here:

```
>>> for obj in objs: weak_s.add(obj)
```

That variable retains its last value from the loop, so it's still referring to the last `Greek` instance, keeping it alive and in the `WeakSet`.